# Unable to highlight text in textboxes in IE9

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, textbox, mouse

I have C# MVC web app that has some textboxes that in IE9 you can enter in text, but you can't highlight via the mouse or via holding shift and the arrow keys.

I've looked around on the web and i've found other people experiencing this, with no solution.

One site i found claimed it was an issue with IE9 on pages that make multiple AJAX calls, which my site has but, removing AJAX really isn't a solution.

Is there a way via code or via settings in IE9 so that users can highlight text in a textbox?  Or is this an outstanding bug in IE9?

Edit:
The website works perfectly fine in chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a rogue jquery statement that was

## (.someClass).disableSelected()

that was disabling selection on every single textbox in my site.  The kicker being that IE and Chrome handled it one way and Firefox a different way making it seem like a different bug

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. 
Select Tools on the IE bar / F12 developer tools. under the tab ( Document Mode IE9 standards ) check marked Alt+9. Closed the developer box. Closed IE9 opened it back up and everything worked as it should.
Hope this helps.