# Clicking on a textbox in firefox doesn't give focus

Tags: jquery, firefox, textbox, mouse

I have the problem where none of the textboxes in my website can get focus if you click on them with the mouse.  If you tab through the items, you can enter data into the textbox.

I have a simliar issue that may be related in IE where clicking gives focus, but I am unable to highlight any of the text [Unable to highlight text in textboxes in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577328/unable-to-highlight-text-in-textboxes-in-ie9)

This however works perfectly fine chrome.

This is a MVC.NET app using jquery

Comment: Got a demo, or are you able to set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net)? We can't solve an issue we can't examine :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out it was a rogue jquery statement that was

## (.someClass).disableSelection()

that was disabling selection on every single textbox in my site.  The kicker being that IE and Chrome handled it one way and Firefox a different way making it seem like a different bug

Comment: Thank you!  I was having the exact same problem and it was proving very difficult to troubleshoot.  I quick grep revealed the culprit.  As an aid to future greppers, it's ".disableSelection()" not ".disableSelected()".

Comment: thanx bmode, I updated the answer to reflect the correct method name

Comment: Would not have thought of this. Thank you!!